# C - Can I use scanf to pause a loop wating for the user to press Enter?

Tags: c, user-interface, scanf

Within a loop, I need to pause waiting for the user to ask to continue by pressing the enter key.

Is okay to use the `scanf()` function inside a loop to pause and wait for the user to press enter to continue? What I need is like in a RPG where you need to press `A` to see the rest of a dialogue.

From what I tested, this function seems to be a poor choice for pausing.

If this is the case, is there any other way to produce this behaviour in C?

Comment: What if the user presses one or more other keys before [enter]?  Should such keystrokes be ignored?

Comment: MSVC has the non-standard `getch()` which returns when any key is pressed and you can then check it is `'A'`. Usually pressing `Enter` is used and `fgets()` is a simple way to do this ignore any other key presses which were not `Enter`. I don't know why there isn't a standard C library function which returns when one key (apart from `Enter`) was pressed and it seems like a massive oversight to me.

Comment: @WeatherVane, it seems reasonable to suppose that the C standard library does not have such a function because it is designed to support an I/O model in which it is not possible to detect individual keystrokes when they happen.  And such models are still widely used even today.

Comment: Well, you can throw the keyboard into non-cannonical mode on Linux and mimic the `getch()` behavior -- which initially may seem like an overkill, but once written you could call it `getch()` if you like (cough... yuck...)

Answer (score 2):

getchar() would be better. If you just want a block-until-user-hits-enter this would be your lowest cost, lowest fail solution. You could ignore the result. This updated answer is an alternative to the very nice do...while loop offered elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

....

while(thing_is_happening) {
  /* do some stuff */
  for(int c = 1; c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar());
  /* do some more stuff */
}
```

Comment: Low cost -- yes.  Low fail -- maybe.  This generally will indeed block until the user has pressed the enter key, but if they press any other keys before enter then the next attempt to do the same thing *will not* block.  On some systems you can push the behavior one way or another by configuring the terminal parameters, but no matter what, one call to `getchar()` does not by itself provide waiting for an enter keypress and discarding whatever other keypresses occur until then.

Comment: John... fair point: it leaves the stdin buffer sitting there for next access. That could be surprising.

Answer (score 2):

I have this function in my library:

```c
void    alx_wait4enter(void)
{
    int c;

    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while ((c != '\n') && (c != EOF));
}
```

It has worked for me.

You just call it and it blocks until enter:

```c
foo();
alx_wait4enter(); // Block here until enter
bar();
alx_wait4enter(); // Block again
foobar();
```

AFAIK, it deals properly with garbage input before an enter, and can be used in a loop or any other context, even in a ncurses program.

Comment: This is the better answer than mine. I'm going to fix mine, but for the record, Cacahuete Frito puts it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> Is okay to use the `scanf()` function inside a loop to pause and wait
>   for the user to press enter to continue?

Supposing that the standard input is connected to a terminal with a typical configuration, calling any input function that reads from the standard input will block until the enter key is pressed, *provided that the input buffer is empty*.  If it is nonempty, however, then it depends what is in the buffer already and on the details of what function is used.

Depending on exactly what you want, `scanf()` can be quite a good alternative, but there are some gotchas involved.  Overall, `scanf()` is tricky to use correctly.

> What I need is like in a RPG
>   where you need to press A to see the rest of a dialogue.

If you're reading from the standard input, you need to understand that typical terminals line-buffer data going to the program.  That means that they will store up typed characters until either `[enter]` is pressed or its buffer fills, and only at that point send the data to the program.  The upshot is that it's tricky to wait for any keypress *but* `[enter]`.

On the other hand, you have to be aware of the possibility that other keys will be pressed before `[enter]`.  There are various things you might choose to do with that situation, but if you haven't anything else to do, then you should probably just drain all everything from the input until you reach a newline.

> From what I tested, this function seems to be a poor choice for pausing.

You haven't described what kind of testing you did, but `scanf()` is tricky to use correctly.  Nevertheless, I think it's a good choice for what you're trying to do.  One of the things to watch out for, however, is that a newline in the format string does not mean "match one newline". Rather, any run of one or more whitespace characters in the format string means "match zero or more whitespace characters", and the function cannot know it has reached the end of a whitespace run until it sees the *next*, non-whitespace character (or end-of-file).

Here's how I would use `scanf` to wait for an `[enter]` keypress, with discarding anything up to that:

```
char c;
int n;

c = 0;
switch(scanf("%*[^\n]%c", &c)) {
    case 1:   // a newline was scanned, corresponding to an [enter] keypress
        assert(c == '\n');
        break;
    case 0:   // the next character was a newline, or an error or EOF occurred
        n = getchar();         // consume the newline
        if (n == '\n') break;  // else it was actually error or EOF
        assert(n == EOF);
        // fall through
    case EOF: // end-of-file was reached or an I/O error occurred
        break;
    default:  // should not happen
        break;
}
```

The `scanf` format specifies exactly what I described.  The `%*[^\n]` field descriptor says to match a sequence of one or more non-newlines, but not assign them anywhere.  This eats up any characters preceding the next newline.  If thatsucceeds, then the `%c` reads the following character, which must be a newline.

The return value of `scanf()` tells you what really happened -- specifically, how many input fields were matched *and assigned*, or the special value `EOF` in the event that end-of-file or an I/O error occurs before anything is matched.  In particular, if the first character available to `scanf` is a newline then nothing can be matched to the first field, so nothing will be consumed from the stream and 0 will be returned.  In that case, you must try to consume the newline from the stream via another mechanism, and `getchar()` serves admirably in that role.  A return value of 1 tells you that at least one non-newline character was matched (but not assigned), then a character that cannot have been anything other than a newline was matched and assigned.

Since there is only one field in the format for which assignment is not suppressed, the only conforming return values are `0`, `1`, and `EOF`.

But after looking at that for a bit, however, I would probably replace it with this:

```
int c;

do {
    c = getchar();
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
// ... optionally handle the c == EOF case here ...
```